# Failed to set existing value for drop down list on edit page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

First thing, I have pre-defined model from existing db. 
I just want to show existing value on edit page with MVC 5.

Here's what I have done:

**Controller**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Guid? id)
{
     if (id == null)
     {
         return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
     }
     slik_data_a01 slik_data_a01 = await db.slik_data_a01.FindAsync(id);
     if (slik_data_a01 == null)
     {
         return HttpNotFound();
     }
     //init DD

     var selectedjs = (from x in db.master_segmenfasilitas
                       where x.sandi == slik_data_a01.kode_jenis_segmen
                       select new { x.fasilitas, x.sandi }).FirstOrDefault();
     var jenissegmen = new SelectList((from x in db.master_segmenfasilitas
                                       select new { x.fasilitas, x.sandi }).ToList(), "sandi", "fasilitas", selectedjs);


     ViewBag.jenissegmen = jenissegmen;
     return View(slik_data_a01);
}
```

And my view is like this :

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.kode_jenis_segmen, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.kode_jenis_segmen, ViewBag.jenissegmen as SelectList, new{ @class = "form-control input-sm" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.kode_jenis_segmen, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

but the default value always shows the first data of the `SelectList`,
not the existing one, although I have defined the selected values on controller.

Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Your binding to property`kode_jenis_segmen` and its that value which determines what is selected. Setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` (the 4th parameter of the `SelectList` constructor is ignored when bind to a model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been trying all the way around to solve this and the simple answer is i cannot assign selected value on model that doesn't have relation in the model.

The only way is that i need to update my model, or create another model which represent my data in the form (CMIIW).

But i found a simple hack, that doesn't require changes in the model, still not perfect but its just fine for me.

here's my updated controller :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Guid? id)
{
     if (id == null)
     {
         return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
     }
     var slik_data_a01 = await db.slik_data_a01.FindAsync(id);
     if (slik_data_a01 == null)
     {
         return HttpNotFound();
     }
     //init Dropdown Data    
    ViewBag.jenissegmen = new SelectList((from x in db.master_segmenfasilitas
                                       select new { x.fasilitas, x.sandi }).ToList()
    /*OrderByDescending to put the selected value on first row*/
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.sandi == slik_data_a01.kode_jenis_segmen)
    , "sandi", "fasilitas");


    //then return to the view.
     return View(slik_data_a01);
}
```

and the view still using the `Html.DropDownListFor`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the selected value in the model property that is binded with the DropDownListFor helper before passing the object to View method at last line and you don't need to set the selected value in the `SelectList` constructor, so change the `SelectList` creation code to be:

```
var jenissegmen = new SelectList((from x in db.master_segmenfasilitas
                                  select new { x.fasilitas, x.sandi }).ToList(), 
                                  "sandi", 
                                  "fasilitas");
```

and before passing model set selected value in the model property, and helper will take care itself for selecting the value:

```
slik_data_a01.kode_jenis_segmen = selectedjs;
ViewBag.jenissegmen = jenissegmen;
return View(slik_data_a01);
```

Now the control will set the selected value on the basis of the value coming in the property which is binded with it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: i have added my research on answer below, i think i cannot assign my selected value, unless i change my model, or using ajax, or using dropdownlist. Thanks for your effort.